# PL/SQL Ttrigger select data from 2 tables with the same row

Tags: plsql

i have a probelm with a little project.
I have these tables:

```
USER (TAG VARCHAR, NICKNAME VARCHAR, TAG_CLAN VARCHAR)
DONATION(DATE_DON DATE, DON_SEND VARCHAR, DON_REIC VARCHAR)
```

THE ELEMENTS: DON_SEND AND DON_REICV ARE THE FOREIGN KEY THAT POINTS TO THE MANI (TAG) OF THE TABLE USER.

I'm trying to make a trigger that allows users to make and receive donations only if the TAG_CLAN is the same

I tried in this way but it doesn't work:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER CONTROLLO_USER_DONAZIONE
BEFORE INSERT ON DONAZIONE
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE 
TAG_C1      UTENTE.NUM_CLAN%TYPE;
TAG_C2      UTENTE.NUM_CLAN%TYPE;
CLAN_DIFF   EXCEPTION;
BEGIN
SELECT U.NUM_CLAN INTO TAG_C1
FROM DONAZIONE D JOIN UTENTE U ON D.COD_UTENTE_EFFETTUA=U.TAG_USER
WHERE D.COD_UTENTE_EFFETTUA=(:NEW.COD_UTENTE_EFFETTUA);
SELECT U.NUM_CLAN INTO TAG_C2
FROM DONAZIONE D JOIN UTENTE U ON D.COD_UTENTE_RICEVE=U.TAG_USER
WHERE D.COD_UTENTE_RICEVE=(:NEW.COD_UTENTE_RICEVE);
IF TAG_C1<>TAG_C2 THEN
    RAISE CLAN_DIFF;
END IF;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN CLAN_DIFF THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20003,'NON SIETE NELLO STESSO CLAN, QUINDI NON PUOI RICEVERE/DONARE CARTE!');
END;
```

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some differences between the tables you posted and the code of your trigger. With tables like these:

```
CREATE TABLE utente
(
    TAG_USER                                VARCHAR2(10) PRIMARY KEY,
    NICKNAME                                VARCHAR2(10),
    NUM_CLAN                                VARCHAR2(10)
);

CREATE TABLE DONAZIONE
(
    DATE_DON                                DATE,
    COD_UTENTE_EFFETTUA                     VARCHAR2(10)     REFERENCES utente(TAG_USER),
    COD_UTENTE_RICEVE                       VARCHAR2(10)     REFERENCES utente(TAG_USER)
);
```

This could be your trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER CONTROLLO_USER_DONAZIONE
    BEFORE INSERT
    ON DONAZIONE
    FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    TAG_C1                                  UTENTE.NUM_CLAN%TYPE;
    TAG_C2                                  UTENTE.NUM_CLAN%TYPE;
    CLAN_DIFF                               EXCEPTION;
BEGIN
    SELECT U.NUM_CLAN
      INTO TAG_C1
      FROM UTENTE U
     WHERE U.TAG_USER = :NEW.COD_UTENTE_EFFETTUA;

    SELECT U.NUM_CLAN
      INTO TAG_C2
      FROM UTENTE U
     WHERE U.TAG_USER = :NEW.COD_UTENTE_RICEVE;

    IF TAG_C1 <> TAG_C2
    THEN
        RAISE CLAN_DIFF;
    END IF;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN CLAN_DIFF
    THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20003, 'NON SIETE NELLO STESSO CLAN, QUINDI NON PUOI RICEVERE/DONARE CARTE!');
END;
```

With data like the following:

```
insert into utente(TAG_USER, NICKNAME, NUM_CLAN) values ('one', 'User one', 'Numbers');
insert into utente(TAG_USER, NICKNAME, NUM_CLAN) values ('two', 'User two', 'Numbers');
insert into utente(TAG_USER, NICKNAME, NUM_CLAN) values ('a', 'User a', 'Letters');
```

it works like:

```
SQL> insert into donazione(DATE_DON, COD_UTENTE_EFFETTUA, COD_UTENTE_RICEVE) values (sysdate, 'one', 'two');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into donazione(DATE_DON, COD_UTENTE_EFFETTUA, COD_UTENTE_RICEVE) values (sysdate, 'a', 'two');
insert into donazione(DATE_DON, COD_UTENTE_EFFETTUA, COD_UTENTE_RICEVE) values (sysdate, 'a', 'two')
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20003: NON SIETE NELLO STESSO CLAN, QUINDI NON PUOI RICEVERE/DONARE CARTE!
ORA-06512: at "ALEK.CONTROLLO_USER_DONAZIONE", line 23
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'ALEK.CONTROLLO_USER_DONAZIONE'
```

The issue in your code is that you do a join, assuming that the record you're inserting already exists in the table `DONAZIONE`, this getting a no_data_found exception.

As an aside, I changed `varchar` into `varchar2`; have a look at the difference between them.

Also, this assumes that `NUM_CLAN` always is `NOT NULL`.

EDIT:

Given the way you need to handle null values, you can edit the IF

```
IF TAG_C1 <> TAG_C2
```

into

```
IF TAG_C1 <> TAG_C2 or TAG_C1 is null or TAG_C2 is null
```

or, more compact, but less readable:

```
IF nvl(TAG_C1, 'a value that a clan can never have') <> nvl(TAG_C2 , 'some other impossible value')
```

Comment: thank you so much for the help, but there is a problem, NUM_CLAN  isn't NOT NULL because a user may not be in any clan

Comment: So what to do if a user is in a clan and the other one not? And what if both users are not in a clan?

Comment: just the user of the same clan can send/receive cards.
the user that are not in a clan can't send/receive to anyone.

Comment: just showed a way. some boolean logic can be useful here

Comment: thank you so much for your help! I appreciated it so much